# How to make buttons visible only for admin in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, view, identity

So I have a view which is list of movies for example (in table).

So now I want to have a button like *remove* or *edit* to every position, but visible only when logged on admin account.

- Should I make 2 controllers and 2 views (one for admin, one for regular user) ?
- Is there any way to share the same view with some hidden options like edit and remove for user ?
- Is there any better way to do it than `IsUserInRole("Administrator")`

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET MVC, or Web Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I make 2 controllers and 2 views (one for admin, one for regular user) ?

You can use 1 controller and 1 view, or 1 controller and 2 views, or 2 controllers and 2 views.  It depends on how much code re-use you get from each choice and also what sort of extensibility you are planning for.  If admins get a lot of additional features, and/or it requires the page to lay out differently, you probably want to use 2 views and 1 controller.

> Is there any way to share the same view with some hidden options like edit and remove for user ?

Yes.  Just enclose the conditional controls in an `if` statement (e.g. `if (IsUserInRole("Administrator") {@Html.ControlFor(m => m.Something)}`.  Depending on the layout of your page it may be easier to enclose an entire DIV instead of working control by control.

In addition to using role to restrict what controls are rendered, you MUST also restrict what actions can be called (i.e. add code to the action handler that checks role).  Otherwise a malicious user can spoof the HTTP traffic associated with the hidden controls and do something he's not supposed to be able to do.

> Is there any better way to do it than IsUserInRole("Administrator")

No, not really.  You could write some extension methods or other functions that call `IsUserInRole` but somewhere in your code you're going to have to call it at some point.